# postgres primary key cambiar change

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-9.3

Hola teniendo una tabla creada quisiera saber si puedo cambiar la primary key por ejemplo para mi tabla donde quiero que `anho` sea la nueva primary key en ves de `id`

```
id | anho | modelo
------------------
 1 | 2010 | new 

 2 | 2015 | new2

 3 | 2018 | new

 4 | 2034 | new2
```

Answer (score 0):

Te dejare el siguiente codigo:

```
-- 1. ELIMINANDO LA CLAVE PRIMARIA
ALTER TABLE mi_tabla DROP CONSTRAINT clave_primaria_actual
-- 2. Creando la nueva clave primaria
ALTER TABLE mi_tabla ADD PRIMARY KEY  nueva_clave_primaria
```

Espero te sirva... solo debes cambiar la tabla y tus claves primarias..!!

Comment: Amigo por una extraña razon me genera un error al momento de eliminar la primary  key asi que segui investigando acontinuacion publico mi respuesta gracias por tu aporte

Comment: @NEFEGAGO cuando pasen estas cosas, añade a tu pregunta (editándola) lo que intentaste y el error que sale. Técnicamente no hay diferencia entre esta respuesta y la tuya más allá de que intentaste hacer un drop con un nombre de pk equivocado (presumo)

Answer (score 0):

lo he resuelto de la siguiente manera:

```
--elimino la primary key correspondiente a la tabla
ALTER TABLE {NombreDeTabla} DROP CONSTRAINT {NombreDeTabla}_pkey;

-- luego asigno la primary key a la tabla con el nuevo nuevo campo(anho)
ALTER  TABLE  {NombreDeTabla} ADD PRIMARY KEY (anho);
```

> Nota: Reemplazar {NombreDeTabla} por el nombre de vuestra tabla

Comment: Pues, el nombre del constraint depende de como se defina la tabla. Es posible dar un nombre al constraint de la PK diferente al estándar que usa la BD, así que esta respuesta, aunque funciona en tu caso, no aplica para todos, siempre.